# Predict if a snapshot is corrupted

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I am working with Aurora postgres on AWS ans I have snapshots for the DB cluster.
I want to predict in case of a disaster, if the snapshot will work as expected to restore the cluster or not, is there any way I can regularly check the integrity of the snapshot before the disaster happens?

Comment: With any kind of backup checking, the only 100% reliable system is to restore the backup and run some queries against it to check that the data you expected to be there is.

Comment: yeah but the cluster is very heavy and I would expect 30-60 minutes restore time and also in terms of costs it's not that convient to spawn another cluster and test stuff out in it

Comment: So trust the AWS snapshot tech then. It's presumably a filesystem-supported snapshot and designed to be atomic. If you don't trust the snapshot and aren't prepared to examine it then I don't know what else you could do.

Comment: Would a corrupted production database and a corrupted backup be a problem for your organization? If not, don't worry about the backup. If it is a problem, you have to test your backup daily. A backup that hasn't been tested, is just not reliable.

Comment: and from there comes my questions, how to daily test backups?